# Disable the startscreen when opening Blender

Tags: blender

When I open blender 2.64, it automatically shows the start/splash screen (I mean the little box in the middle of the page where you can open recent .blend files). I Would like to disable this, but cannot find out how. Does anybody know?

You might wonder: why would you want that? Well, I have an external program that opens blender and shows a scene. This for a presentation. I really don't like how I have to manually close the startscreen before you can actually see the scene.

Note: I do not need to actually render something, I want Blender to stay in edit mode after showing the scene. Opening blender in the background and rendering a scene and then getting that image and than showing that rendered image instead is NOT what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Under **Edit** > **Preferences**, there's a tab called **Interface**.

On that tab, there should be an option called **Splash Screen**. Just uncheck that box and the splash screen will be gone forever.

[image]